# Can one create iOS dynamic libraries for iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode, restcomm

I know that since iOS 8 it is possible to ship dynamic frameworks and use them as 'Embedded Binaries' in your App, which is great.

What I was wondering though if it is possible to do the same for a dynamic library (ie .dylib), that is ship a dynamic library together with its headers for other devs to use. I tried adding a .dylib in Embedded Binaries in Xcode but it seems it isn't allow for some reason. Searching around also wasn't able to find something

Any hints?

Reason I need that instead of framework is that it makes it easier to ship existing linux libraries (for example using the auto tools build system) very easily.

Thanks a lot,
Antonis